# Swift protocol extensions and immutable properties

Tags: swift, properties, protocol-extension

I'm new to Swift and playing with protocol extensions. In the following code I can't seem to protect the struct property `holdings` from direct manipulations.

```swift
enum BankingError: Error {
    case insufficientFunds
}

protocol Banking {
    var holdings: Int { get set }
    mutating func deposit(_ amount: Int)
    mutating func withdraw(_ amount: Int) throws
}

extension Banking {    
    mutating func deposit(_ amount: Int) {
        holdings += amount
    }
    
    mutating func withdraw(_ amount: Int) throws {
        guard amount <= holdings else { throw BankingError.insufficientFunds }
        holdings -= amount
    }
}

struct Bank: Banking {
    var holdings: Int
}

// Usage
var bank = Bank(holdings: 0)
bank.deposit(1)
try bank.withdraw(1)
do {
    try bank.withdraw(1)
} catch BankingError.insufficientFunds {
    print("Computer says 'No'")
}
// Disallow direct mutation of holdings?
bank.holdings = 0
bank.holdings += 1
bank.holdings -= 2
// Getter is OK
print(bank.holdings)
```

If the methods were implemented as part of the struct I could have declared `holdings`as `private(set)`, is there an equivalent option in this case?

Comment: It would be much easier to solve this without the default implementations of the functions in your extension. You have limited the usefulness of the protocol quite much in my opinion with that extension

Comment: Well, yes, but this is part of an experiment with protocol composition, hence the default implementations. As an example, a protocol `Trading` would combine `Banking` with `Storing` and get the default implementations "for free". At least that was how I thought I could use protocols...

Comment: Yes but you might as well have a Bank struct without the protocol and then use that as a property type in your Trading protocol, right now you don't gain much from having a protocol.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear, sorry. I’m not looking for an alternative solution, but rather an explanation to why it is not possible to protect the property when using default implementations in protocol extensions. The code example in just a boiled down example of a much larger part of a complex project that would benefit from massive decoupling.

Comment: One solution would be to declare the property as read only, `var holdings: Int { get }` but then the functions in the extension won't compile. Another solution would be to remove the property altogether and let the conforming types decide how to persist the holding value but again this would create compilation errors in the extension.

Comment: This is a case where `fileprivate` comes in. Only having a reader for `holdings` might be even better, but IMO, the whole example is challenging, because banking is way more important that depositing and withdrawing. E.g. even depositing can `throw` (e.g. contributing to registered retirement account above its annual cap). Further bank accounts *never* have a stored balance, they have a ledger of debits and credits, from which a balance is _derived_.

Comment: More generally, if you want to strongly enforce API access, you need a module boundary. `fileprivate` works in a pinch, but e.g. nothing prevents another dev on your team from added code to the file which circumvents other public APIs in the file. If there call is coming from inside the house, there's not much you can do without imposing a module boundary.